# Save the List value during the post back, its get cleared when i try to access the list after clicking the button each time in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Controller:**

```
List<EmployeeSkill> emp = new List<EmployeeSkill>();
public ActionResult viewskills(EmployeeSkill objskillset)
{
    emp .Add(objskillset);
    return PartialView("_SkillListPartial", objskillset);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Skill")]
public string SkillName { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Experience (In Months)")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Experience(In Months)")]
public Nullable<byte> ExperienceInMonths { get; set; }
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }

public virtual EmployeeDetail EmployeeDetail { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
model IEnumerable<CISSEC.Models.EmployeeSkill> 
<table class="table"> 
    <tr> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SkillName) </th> 
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExperienceInMonths)</th> 
    </tr> 
  @foreach (var item in Model) { 
      <tr> 
          <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SkillName) </td> 
          <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExperienceInMonths) </td> 
     </tr> 
  } 
</table>
```

Comment: Please show how you render the list into the `<form>` you are submitting.

Comment: { model IEnumerable<CISSEC.Models.EmployeeSkill>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SkillName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExperienceInMonths)
        </th>


    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SkillName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExperienceInMonths)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>

Answer (score 0):

Your list is not posted back because you do not render `<input>` elements for the properties of the list items. Use `HiddenFor` to render the inputs. Use a `for` loop so the modelbinder receives the correct index of the list items.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) { 
      <tr> 
          <td> @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].SkillName) </td> 
          <td> @Html.HiddenFor(m=> m[i].ExperienceInMonths) </td> 
     </tr> 
}
```